# Access Azure File Storage from on-premise machine via virtual network that is connected with virtual network gateway (site-to-site connection)

Tags: azure

I've setup an azure virtual network gateway with a virtual network and connected it to our on-premise network. I added a subnet in the virtual network. The plan was to have a file share in that subnet and map it on on-premise windows machines, similar as a classic SMB file share. So, we added a GPv1 storage account and assigned the VN subnet to that account. After the storage account was ready I was not able to add a file storage (authorization failure) until I figured out that I have to add IP ranges to allow access from the internet or  "on-premises networks". Since the on-premise network is connected via the VN gateway I expected that I have to add the on-premise network IP range. However, the configuration allows only public IP addresses and thus I added our public IP address. Then I was able to add file storage to the storage account. When inspecting the file storage properties I can see only a public URL to access the storage but no internal IP address or internal URL in the virtual private network's subnet. The actual question is: Is there any way to access the file storage in Azure via the site-to-site connected virtual network or is it only possible via the public URL? If only via public URL, what sense makes an assignment of the storage account to the virtual network in azure? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand it is only accessible through the public UNC path.

The purpose of assigning a virtual network subnet access to a storage account, is to strictly limit access to only resources within the virtual network subnet (private addresses). Otherwise the storage account will be accessible from any location. This also ensures traffic transits over the Azure backbone.

Comment: If the assignment of a virtual network subnet access to a storage account strictly limits the access to only resources within the virtual network subnet: does it mean that I cannot even access it via internet through the public URL with the provided pass-key?

Comment: @Hagen Yes that’s correct. It’s like isolating the storage account to the subnet via firewall rules. You would have to manually allow a public source through to the storage account.